# How to force control to immediately update itself in Android?

Tags: c#, android

I have a situation when I need to redraw control immediately. Here is one basic example:

```
editText.setText("some text");
// some code to redraw control immediately.
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Normally, control will be updated when this method exits, at the event processing stack frame, after 10 minutes late. Is there some way to process this event out of order, in top of the current stack. In `C#` I would achieve this by calling `Application.DoEvents()`.

I know that this is normally achieving by doing long execution async, but in simple case like this it would be unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to process this event out of order, in top of the current stack

No, for the simple reason that you are tying up the main application thread, which processes the events.